How to configure VNC server for Lubuntu (LXQt)?
I have installed TightVNC server (apt install tightvncserver) and created a file ~/.vnc/xstartup with the following content:
#!/bin/bash

[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
xsetroot -solid grey
#unset SESSION_MANAGER
#unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
startlxqt &

Command to start VNC server (started as a service as described here):
vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 -localhost :1


When I connect via VNC the desktop looks like that:

⇒ The taskbar is missing (gray bar) and most of the desktop icons are missing.

There is a prominent error in the syslog:
kernel: lxqt-config-mon[21621]: segfault at 10 ip 0000731cabe1c1d4 sp 00007ffc4fa80850 error 4 in libKF5Screen.so.5.27.11[731cabe15000+24000] likely on CPU 1 (core 1, socket 0)
kernel: Code: 40 35 c3 90 66 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8b 47 10 40 88 70 35 c3 90 66 90 f3 0f 1e fa 55 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 08 <4c> 8b 66 10 49 8b 44 24 28 8b 10 85 d2 74 2d 83 fa ff 75 18 48 89


All lines from syslog:
systemd[1]: Starting vncserver@1.service - Start TightVNC server at startup...
vncserver[21501]: Can't find file /home/eg/.vnc/eg-host:1.pid
vncserver[21501]: You'll have to kill the Xtightvnc process manually
vncserver[21506]: New 'X' desktop is eg-host:1
vncserver[21506]: Starting applications specified in /home/eg/.vnc/xstartup
vncserver[21506]: Log file is /home/eg/.vnc/eg-host:1.log
systemd[1]: Started vncserver@1.service - Start TightVNC server at startup.
dbus-daemon[21551]: [session uid=1001 pid=21549] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Activating service name='org.kde.KScreen' requested by ':1.5' (uid=1001 pid=21621 comm="/usr/bin/lxqt-config-monitor -l" label="unconfined")
org.kde.KScreen[21649]: qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
org.kde.KScreen[21649]: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-eg'
spice-vdagent[21672]: vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0 does not exist, exiting
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1001 pid=21641 comm="/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.KScreen'
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
kernel: lxqt-config-mon[21621]: segfault at 10 ip 0000731cabe1c1d4 sp 00007ffc4fa80850 error 4 in libKF5Screen.so.5.27.11[731cabe15000+24000] likely on CPU 1 (core 1, socket 0)
kernel: Code: 40 35 c3 90 66 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8b 47 10 40 88 70 35 c3 90 66 90 f3 0f 1e fa 55 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 08 <4c> 8b 66 10 49 8b 44 24 28 8b 10 85 d2 74 2d 83 fa ff 75 18 48 89
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1001 pid=21641 comm="/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1001 pid=21641 comm="/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor'
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1001 pid=21641 comm="/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1001 pid=21641 comm="/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor'
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1001 pid=21641 comm="/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
NetworkManager[539]: <info>  [1715628192.0475] agent-manager: agent[648f45b9379275c0,:1.145/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1001]: agent registered
dbus-daemon[505]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' unit='blueman-mechanism.service' requested by ':1.149' (uid=1001 pid=21625 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet" label="unconfined")
systemd[1]: Starting blueman-mechanism.service - Bluetooth management mechanism...
dbus-daemon[505]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
systemd[1]: Started blueman-mechanism.service - Bluetooth management mechanism.
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Activating service name='org.bluez.obex' requested by ':1.22' (uid=1001 pid=21625 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[505]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.149' (uid=1001 pid=21625 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet" label="unconfined")
systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).
obexd[21849]: OBEX daemon 5.72
dbus-daemon[21578]: [session uid=1001 pid=21576] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez.obex'


When I execute lxqt-config-monitor -l in the VNC session, I get this error:
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-eg'
[load.applyBestSettings()] Finished
org.kde.kscreen: Failed to request backend: unknown error
lxqt-config-monitor: Applying current settings...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


The VNC log itself looks OK so far:
13/05/24 22:57:56 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
13/05/24 22:57:56 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
13/05/24 22:57:56 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
13/05/24 22:57:56 All Rights Reserved.
13/05/24 22:57:56 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
13/05/24 22:57:56 Desktop name 'X' (eg-host:1)
13/05/24 22:57:56 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
13/05/24 22:57:56 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring

13/05/24 22:58:11 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
13/05/24 22:58:11 Using protocol version 3.8
13/05/24 22:58:11 Enabling TightVNC protocol extensions
13/05/24 22:58:11 Full-control authentication passed by 127.0.0.1
13/05/24 22:58:12 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
13/05/24 22:58:12   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
13/05/24 22:58:12   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
13/05/24 22:58:12   no translation needed
13/05/24 22:58:12 Using tight encoding for client 127.0.0.1
13/05/24 22:58:12 Using compression level 1 for client 127.0.0.1
13/05/24 22:58:12 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
13/05/24 22:58:12 Enabling cursor position updates for client 127.0.0.1
13/05/24 22:58:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -768
13/05/24 22:58:12 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
13/05/24 22:58:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223



Note: I have a fresh Lubuntu 24.04 minimal installation.

How to configure the VNC server for Lubuntu 24.04 with LXQt correctly?
